# How can I scroll the text on image in xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

[image]

hear is my code:

```
var label = new UILabel { Text = text };

  label.SetNeedsLayout();

  float width = 125;

  SizeF size = (SizeF)(label.Text).StringSize(label.Font, new SizeF(width, 100),UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation);

  label.Lines = 5;

  label.Frame = new RectangleF(20, 40, size.Width, size.Height);

  var image = new UIImageView();

  image.Image = new UIImage("bluesticky.png");

  image.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 180, 220);

  this.AddSubview(image);

  this.AddSubview(label);
```

In my code `UILabel` text is placed on `UIImage`. If the text is larger than the image I want to scroll the text on image.How can I get like that If I have large amount of text. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its difficult with  UIlable - You can do but you will also need scrollview.

Use UITextView instead. Change background color to clear editable property to false. It will automatically manage scroll.

///Update:
To disable dragging of image when Your textView is scrolling, you can disable Dragging event of UIImageview when scroll started and Enable again when scroll ended.

```
mytextview1.DecelerationStarted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                //Disable dragging of Image. 
            };
            mytextview1.DecelerationEnded += (sender, e) =>
            {
                //Enable dragging of Image.
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.I am using UITextView instead of UILabel, It work's fine but I face some other problem using UITextView.i.e for my image is dragging feature is present. If I am try to scroll text in UIImage with the scroll bar my image also moving.please suggest any solution.

Comment: Can you please share screenshot from your app - I want to understand it before suggesting solution.

Comment: I added screen shot. please see and and suggest any solution.

Comment: If you want scrolling in Text inside image and also want dragging of Image, I think you should start dragging only after Long Press on Image.